# GIT merge with conflicts generated message appears

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-git

I am learning how to work with Git. On windows with VS Code. I am learning merge with conflicts. After resolving commit conflicts, I will see an auto-generated commit message containing a list of conflicting files. It opens automatically in the built-in GIT terminal. There is nothing more I can do. I press :q or :wq it does not work. Everywhere they write that you just need to save, I don't know how to do it.
[image]
I saw on YouTube how one person opens a separate window in VS Code in which he can save this message and work further, but there is no way to set it up.[image]
Please tell me what I need to do while in the terminal or how to set up the editor for such messages.

Comment: What do you mean with "I press :q or :wq it does not work"? Isn't a merge commit created with the message "Merge branch 'v1'"? (Write `git show` to see the last commit.) What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first your `git config --global core.editor` value.

I have set mine to `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --wait`

That should avoid `vim`, which is not well supported in the included Terminal console of VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

**Open VS Code for any type of Git message** (e.g. git merge/git commit etc.) **-**

```
git config --global core.editor 'code --wait'
```

**Open VS Code for diff tool -**

```
git config --global diff.tool vscode
```

**Open VS Code for merge tool -**

```
git config --global merge.tool vscode
```

---

For more check this life-saving article - https://www.roboleary.net/vscode/2020/09/15/vscode-git.html